# Golang regex match string fails only for last substring in a list of strings separated using OR operator |

Tags: regex, go, string-matching

I have a regular expression

**"^test\/053783914460|182782814227|161046048738\/test\/\\S+\/\\d{4}\/"**

that I thought would match this string:
**"test/161046048738/test/random/2021/"**.

But it does not match. Not sure why it fails to match only the last number, when it matches for the other numbers in the list separated by or operator **|**, like "test/182782814227/test/random/2021/"

https://play.golang.org/p/WsB0_C8yhHy is the script that I am trying to understand.

Excuse me for being a newbie in golang regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your fixed code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    path := "test/161046048738/test/random/2021/"
    result, err := regexp.MatchString(`^test/(?:053783914460|182782814227|161046048738)/test/[^/\s]+/\d{4}/`, path)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Value matched regex: ", result)
}
```

See the [Go playground demo](https://play.golang.org/p/PMYw-ER7nXA).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `test/` -  a literal text
- `(?:053783914460|182782814227|161046048738)` - one of the three alternatives
- `/test/` - `/test/` substring
- `[^/\s]+`  - one or more chars other than whitespace and `/`
- `/\d{4}/` - `/`, four digits and a `/` char.

Comment: thank you for this, but I am still trying to understand why mine didn't work. Why can't I use \S+ instead of [^/\s]+?

Comment: Why do we need ?: for one of the 2 alternatives, isn't that why we are using | operator?

Comment: @RiyaJohn `\S` matches `/` chars, if you need to match several parts and not just one, then use `\S+`. `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, it is more efficient than capturing groups especially when you do not use the captured text. You need to group alternatives here.